# Eclipse dark skin

Tags: eclipse, customization, skins

What I'm looking for is a dark skin for Eclipse v3.3 on Win7. I mean not just the code editor in dark, but the whole dark IDE together with toolbars and stuff. I know it's possible in Ubuntu, but I have to stick to Win7 for now and it rips my eyes off.

Comment: One hint would be to stop using eclipse 3.3. The recent 4.2 release has better skinning capabilities

Comment: By the way, how would you do it in ubuntu?

Comment: Well, it's impossible to switch to 4.2 because it is an Eclipse-based tool with tons of extra features.

Comment: Accept my sincere regrets then. AFAIK, there is no way. I too have searched far and wide...

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a collection of steps that get you to a beautiful Dark Theme:  https://github.com/davidcoleman007/VibrantNight

Which tool is it?  Flash Builder?  It can be tricked to work with other versions of eclipse, as you can see in my instructions!  Tell us which tool it is and we might be able to help you hack a newer eclipse to work for you!